# Sparse (dgCMatrix) matrix row-normalization in R

Tags: r, matrix, sparse-matrix

I have a large sparse matrix, call it P:

```
 > str(P)
   Formal class 'dgCMatrix' [package "Matrix"] with 6 slots
   ..@ i       : int [1:7868093] 4221 6098 8780 10313 11102 14243 20570 22145 24468 24977 ...
   ..@ p       : int [1:7357] 0 0 269 388 692 2434 3662 4179 4205 4256 ...
   ..@ Dim     : int [1:2] 1303967 7356
   ..@ Dimnames:List of 2
   .. ..$ : NULL
   .. ..$ : NULL
   ..@ x       : num [1:7868093] 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 ...
   ..@ factors : list()
```

I'd like to row-normalize (say, with the L-2 norm)... (taking advantage of vector-recycling) the straight-forward approach would be something like:

```
> row_normalized_P <- P / rowSums(P^2)
```

But this causes a memory allocation error, since it appears the `rowSums` result is being recycled into a *dense* matrix with dimensions equal to `dim(P)`.
Given that `P` is known to be sparse (or at the very least is stored in sparse format), does anyone know of a non-iterative approach to achieve the desired `row_normalized_P` shown above?
(I.e. the resultant matrix will be equally sparse as `P` itself... and I'd like to avoid ever having a dense matrix allocated during the normalization steps.)

The only semi-efficient method I've found around this is to `apply` across rows (more accurately through blocks of rows coerced into dense sub-matrices) of `P`, but I'd like to try to remove the looping logic from my codebase if I can, and I'm wondering if perhaps there's a built-in in the Matrix package (that I'm just not aware of) that helps with this particular type of computation.

Cheers and thanks for any help!

-murat

Answer (score 4):

I figured out a nice solution (as usual, about 15 minutes after posting :-/ )...

```
> row_normalized_P <- Matrix::Diagonal(x = 1 / sqrt(Matrix::rowSums(P^2))) %*% P
```

Comment: And for col normalization, remember to swap the multiplication order: `P %*% Matrix::Diagonal(x = 1 / sqrt(Matrix::colSums(P^2)))`